# Visual Studio failing to deploy to IOS simulator when Signing Identity is set to anything other than automatic

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, maui

I no longer seem to have separate settings for deploy and release.  I need to have my IOS->Bundle Signing-> Signing identity set to "Apple Distribution" to release but "Developer (Automatic)" to debug.

Previously, this information was saved separately for release and debug, respectively.  Failing to set this back to "Developer (Automatic)" each time I switch back to debug causes the deploy not to succeed and the simulator not to be triggered on the Mac.

Is there a way around having to change this every time?

I was expecting settings to be saved independently for release and debug.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version?

Comment: I have.  That was when I noticed the issue.  Previously there were separate settings for Debug and Release.